# AES-128-CBC decpription return wrong value

Tags: aes, cbc-mode

I tried to create an AES-128-CBC decryption over javascript

Here I did so far:

```
    <script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js"></script>
<script>
 var rawStr = "MyPassword";
      var secret = 'EL12ec@REteLe(0M';
      var wordArray = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(rawStr);
      var base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(wordArray);
      var encrypted = '' + CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(base64, secret);
      console.log('base64:', base64);
      console.log('encrypted:', encrypted);
</script>
```

But the value I got is: `TXlQYXNzd29yZA==`

The correct value is: `S9bEDxeu/jr+8CdRkiUEog==` based on this online encryption tools: https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption

Anyone can help me how to achieved this to get same result encryption same like devglan tools?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

To reproduce the result of the website, the following has to be considered:

- The key must be passed to `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt` as `WordArray`. Otherwise it is interpreted as a passphrase, [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input).
- The CBC mode (CryptoJS default, [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#block-modes-and-padding)) requires an IV, which must be passed to `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt` as `WordArray` (if no IV is specified on the website, a `0`-vector is implicitly used).
- The return value of `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt` is a `CipherParams` object, which encapsulates the ciphertext among other things, [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-output).

```js
var rawStr = "MyPassword";
var secret = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('EL12ec@REteLe(0M');
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0');
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(rawStr, secret, {iv: iv});
console.log('Output:',  CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encrypted.ciphertext)); // Output: S9bEDxeu/jr+8CdRkiUEog==
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```